# separate posts to have (kind of) 2 blogs?

Tags: categories, customization, link-category

Before putting a lot of effort in this, just to find out it's not possible:

Let's say I have two different categories and I want the user
to be locked in one of them after choosing it from a menu-point. If
someone has choosen, e.g. 'announcements', I want Wordpress to do
like there are only posts of this category and ignore the rest.
Or even better, is there a way to divide categories into different blocks
and use them separately? Would this be a job for link-categories?

Answer (score 1):

From you are describing, it might be worth investigating custom-post types. You can actually create a separate menu tab on the left column - ergo separate your posts accordingly in a similar layout as Posts.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Answer (score 0):

Well, at last this was easier than I thought:

So far I created 2 Post-Categories. At least Wordpress 3.2 has the possibility to add categories to menus: Under Appearance -> Menus scroll down to the Categories-frame, choose one and click 'Add to Menu'. It's added as new menuitem on the end and you can drag it around.

If you have your categories in a sidebar they are all shown to the user, so its quite easy to switch between the 'blog-areas'. With a little PHP its probably possible to sort out some of them, especially if you use the parent-feature. But for now I don't show them at all and use tags instead.